# Stop systemd units in different order than start

Tags: systemd

How can I define two systemd units so their Stop order is different than their Start order ?

For performance issue, I have both units A and B start simultaneously (they both start after a systemd socket), but unit A cannot stop before unit B

Comment: Potentially you can use `BindsTo` or `Requires` to achieve this, but from your question it is unclear how exactly are you stopping the services. What exactly triggers the stopping of the services?

Comment: They are both stopped when shuting the system down, so system sends a SIGTERM to both units at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. If B contains `After=A`, A starts first, and B stops first.

What the service manager waits for when starting A depends on the Type. Reference possible types in the [systemd.service manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html). In particular, `simple` doesn't even wait for the exec(), but `forking` waits for the parent process to exit.

If performance is what you are after, naturally there are multiple competing tools for timing the start of units, [systemd-analyze and bootchart](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance/Boot_process#Analyzing_the_boot_process). Determine the maximum startup time you can tolerate, then measure how long it actually takes.

For further improvements, profile this thing in detail and look at its code.

Comment: the units can be linked with `Requires=` or `BindsTo=`. according to documentation, it does not fix the order in which services are started, but influences how they are stopped. (as in, stopping of one of them triggers the stopping of the other)